# Best way to bin all x values within a range and then take the mean of all y values in each bin?

Tags: python, list, range, mean, binning

I have a list of x,y coordinates. The x values are close together but are not the same. I would like to bin x values together within a range and then take the mean value of the y values in each bin. I want the end results to be two 1-D arrays - one of binned x values and the other of the associated y mean values.

As an example, for `list = ((1.0, 10.2), (1.3, 10.1), (1.6, 10.8), (2.3, 12.0), (2.4, 12.7))`,

I would like the output to be: `x = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]` and `y = [10.15, 10.8, 12.35]`.

In the code below, I try scipy's `stats.binned_statistic`, but have not had success as I am unsure how to specify the bin size. In the code below I put 10 elements per bin to try to get it to work, but in reality I would like to specify a range such as all numbers within a range of 0.5 of each other be binned together.

I also looked at `numpy.digitize` but was not if that is what I'm looking for.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

x = [x_values]
y = [corresponding_y_values]
test = stats.binned_statistic(x, y, 'mean', bins=(len(x))/10)
plt.plot(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the same question in the future, I got this to work:

```
y,x,_=stats.binned_statistic(x,l,'mean',bins=np.arange(x[0],x[int(len(x)-1)],(x[int(len(x)-1)]-x[0])/((x[int(len(x)-1)]-x[0])*10)))
```